# How do I use an ASP.net asp:RangeValidator to validate a date properly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, validation

Here's my code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="* License Setup Date">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="LicenseSetupDateRequired" 
            ErrorMessage="License Setup Date can't be blank."
            ValidationGroup="EditClientDetails" 
            ControlToValidate="BeginDate"  
            Text="*!" 
            Display="Dynamic" 
            runat="server"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                    
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="LicenseSetupDateRange" 
            ErrorMessage="License Setup Date needs to be a date between 01/01/2000 and 12/31/2200"
            ValidationGroup="EditClientDetails" 
            ControlToValidate="BeginDate"
            MinimumValue="01/01/2000"
            MaximumValue="12/31/2002"
            Type="Date"
            Text="*!" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"></asp:RangeValidator>                        
        <asp:TextBox ID="BeginDate" MaxLength="10" 
            Text='<%# Bind("BeginDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' 
            runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="fieldNote">(mm/dd/yyyy format)</span>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And the results:

- 01/01/2008 Doesn't pass
- 02/02/2008 Doesn't pass
- 11/11/2000 Passes
- 08/08/2001 Passes

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase MaximumValue to a date which is greater than that of your tests.  Specifically, MaximumValue should be set to 12/31/2200.  You've fat-fingered the MaximumValue.

Comment: Selected for using the term "fat fingered"

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave seems to have a typo.  You specify the MaximumDate as '**31/12/2002**' instead of '**31/12/2200**'.